# Translating theme: Add to cart button?

Tags: bigcartel

I've been translating a theme by simply customizing the HTML, but I've run into a problem:

The "Add to cart" button on a product page. I can translate the label on the button, but when you click the button the text changes from "Add to cart" to "Adding..." and then to "Added!".

Neither "Adding..." nor "Added!" are anywhere to be found the HTML of the theme, so I'm wondering where I should look if I want to translate those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Adding", "Added" response comes from the theme's javascript - unfortunately that's hard-coded in and there's not a way to change it. You may want to try modifying another theme that doesn't use ajax to add products to your cart, like Sexy, Luna, or Nova - then you should be able to have more control over translating your store completely.

Comment: Can't I create my own theme based on an existing theme and then modify the javascript?

Comment: There's not a way to modify the javascript in Big Cartel themes at the moment, sorry about that. You're welcome to include your own, and either load it from a separate webhost or include it inline, but you'll want to make sure it doesn't conflict with the existing theme.js that's loaded.